# Life cycle events of app.component.ts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, lifecycle

**Update:**

Actually, I have implemented "toggle menu" as on this doc.Please see that.The toggle menu is working fine.But I need to get the latest token when a user clicks the toggle menu.It works only with the constructor.After that, I cannot do that.That is may be due to the Root component.How can I achieve that?

[**Ionic2 Toggle Menu**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#menus)

Which life cycle event can I access after creating the `app.component.ts` component? First time it fires `constructor()` code.But after that none of the lifecycle events are working.

**My scenario:** I have implemented side menu as shown below on Ionic2 app.

**app.html**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-content padding>
   <img src="./assets/img/login.png" alt="Login" (click)="login()" *ngIf="token!=null && token.length==0" menuClose>

        //removed for clarity

    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Now I need to get the token value each and every time user clicks on above menu.But it works only once.After that, it's not working.Can you tell me a workaround for this?

**app.component.ts**

```
export class MyApp extends HandleStorageService {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage = EventSchedulePage;
  menuList: Observable<any>;
  token: string = '';

  constructor(platform: Platform, public menuData: MenuData, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public storage: Storage) {
    super(storage);

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });

    this.getMenuList();//menu list
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {// not working this
    this.getToken().then((val) => {//get token
      this.token = val;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Does your app component have a view?

Comment: Actually, I have implemented "toggle menu" as on this doc.Please see that.The toggle menu is working fine.But I need to get the latest token when a user clicks the toggle menu.It works only with the constructor.After that I cannot do that.That is may be the Root component.How can I achieve that? @echonax http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#menus

Comment: I am not sure what token is and what is the exact behaviour you want. But, from the context, I feel I have also faced this type of problem. I wanted to change the menu options when user logs in/logs out. I did this using **Events** in ionic2 - [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/). Does this help you?

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app shows it perfectly.

Comment: Can you please share small code snippet on the answer section? Then I can follow it and try to do the task.Yes, exactly the situation is like yours. I try to implement toggle menu on `app.html` page.But unable to get the token value. @SagarKulkarni Token is used for identifying logged in or not.

Comment: Sure. Answering it with Events approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the flag `isLoggedIn` than `token`. So, your `app.html` will become like this:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-content padding>
   <img src="./assets/img/login.png" alt="Login" (click)="login()" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" menuClose>

        //removed for clarity

    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Now in your `app.ts`, first you subscribe to these events. And you can publish these events from anywhere in the app. These subscriptions in `app.ts` gets triggered as soon as the particular event is published.

`app.ts` code: (Adding just the changes but not an entire code)

```
import {Events} from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyApp extends HandleStorageService{
    isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
    constructor(private events: Events){
        //Below I am assuming you store the 'loggedIn' information in localStorage. You could use your own way for retrieving this value at the start of the app.

        this.isLoggedIn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedIn'));

        this.listenToLoginEvents();
    }

    listenToLoginEvents(){
        this.events.subscribe('user:login', () => {
            console.log("LoggedIn triggered");
            this.loggedIn = true;
        });

        this.events.subscribe('user:logout', () => {
            console.log("Logout triggered");
            this.loggedIn = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Now say you have another component from where you are logging in. There when the login is done you can publish `user:login` event like this:

```
this.events.publish('user:login');
```

Same goes for `user:logout`. Refer [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/) for more clarity on using Events.

Comment: This is a really Cool feature.Thank you very much :)